# Private class method chaining in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How's it possible to chain private class methods in ruby?

```
class Foobar
  private_class_method def self.one
    where(one: true)
  end

  private_class_method def self.two
    where(two: true)
  end

  def self.three
    one.two
  end
end
```

`Foobar.three` results in `undefined method "two" for #<ActiveRecord::Relation>`

Why does this happen and is there a workaround to achieve my desire?

Comment: I guess it's because you defined it as private?

Comment: normally works so drop the private and why not use scopes ? they can also be chained

Comment: @peter i'd like to split functionality because i have some comples scopes but i do not want them to be used separately. That's why i'd like to split up the functionality, name them properly and create a combined scope which is the only thing i want to be publicly available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed it doesnt work because of private methods.

Unfortunately there is no `protected_class_method`.

So I suggest you this approach:

```
class Foobar
  class << self
    def three
      one.two
    end

    protected 
    def one
      where(one: true)
    end

    def two
      where(two: true)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: that is definitly a workaround i'll use because inheritance is not used in my specific use-case. So i'll mark your answer as correct as it fulfills my desire for a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: This should lead to the same `undefined method "two" for #<ActiveRecord::Relation>` error.

Answer (score 1):

So, i've found out why this error message actually happened: private class methods are not callable with a receiver present.

calling `one` results in an ActiveRecord::Relation and calling a private method onto that relation is not allowed, thus resulting in the given error.

There is a small workaround to get this working:

```
def self.three
  one.merge(two)
end
```

The present receiver disappears by calling one and two separately and merging it with the [ActiveRecord merge method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge)

Answer (score 0):

undefined method "two" for `#<ActiveRecord::Relation>` this message came because  `where(one: true)` will give result in array of object not 1 object, so in `self.three` we should run in loop to call.

```
def self.three
    one.map{|x| x.two}
   # or 
   #one.map(&:two)
  end
```